# Reusing notations

Tags: discussion

I have recently asked two questions about the same proof, only for different steps of it. Is it considered good etiquette to refer people to "with notations used in my previous question" along with a link, or should all notations be re-introduced, as well as all already-proven statements?

To clarify on that last bit, if I introduced a set $P$ in a question and proved it was finite, should I remind the reader "let $P=...$, and $P$ is finite"?

Comment: I think linking it should suffice.

Comment: IMHO, one only need to define the most important ones again. For the minor ones, just  give a very quick summary and refer to other questions for details.